# Check JNI calls correctness in Compile time

Tags: java-native-interface, verification, compile-time

We use a banch of JNI calls (C++ -> Java) in our project. Sometimes me rename methods, do refactoring, etc. So it's will be nice to check every call in **compile time**. Calls looks like

```
m_getDeviceIdMid = getEnv()->GetMethodID(jAdapterClass, "getDeviceId",  " ()Ljava/lang/String;");
getEnv()->CallObjectMethod(m_jAdapter, m_getDeviceIdMid)
```

Do you know a way to do it? (Maybe with annotations or something similar)